# How to right align last li?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I am trying to right align the `<div class="right-align">` (last `<li>`) using CSS. I did try to do the following but it did not work.

I need to be able to make the height of `<ul class="third-level">` to automatically adjust as the height of `<div class="right-align">` depending upon length of content inside.

[codepin](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/BqPoLY)

How would I right align the last `<li>`?

**What i tried but did not work because of the height of `<div class="right-align">`**

```css
.third-level {
  position: relative;
  
}

.third-level li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="third-level">
          <li><a href="#">Resets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grids</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frameworks</a></li>
          <li >
            <div class="right-align">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
            <h5>Image placeholder</h5>
            <p>Collaboratively matrix parallel growth strategies rather than emerging "outside the box" thinking. </p>
            
            <a href="#some-path">Some path</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

current issue:

[image: current issue]

desired output:

[image: desired output]

Comment: Yeah, you're not really going to like the solutions that get you there _based on this markup_.  I'd fairly strongly recommend different markup to get you the desired layout.  It'll be much cleaner and more maintainable.

Comment: @cale_b do you have an example markup that you would like to propose as an answer? it can be difficult to image what the recommended markup would be.

Comment: Certainly.  As a starter, your image seems to indicate two columns.  Why not create two columns for presenting the data in?  You could either abandon the `ul` and `li` and simply use `div` containers to create your desired layout, or you could, if you felt the list markup was important, nest it inside of an additional list, eg: `<ul><li class="column left-column"><ul><li>Resets</li><li>Grids</li></ul></li><li class="column right-column"><ul><li>Frameworks</li></ul></li></ul>' - but that seems unneccessary (without knowing more context about your project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set fixed width for `.third-level li:last-child`. Something like 200px or 50% and `top: 0;` to align it to the top.

```css
.third-level {
  position: relative;
  
}

.third-level li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="third-level">
          <li><a href="#">Resets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grids</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frameworks</a></li>
          <li >
            <div class="right-align">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
            <h5>Image placeholder</h5>
            <p>Collaboratively matrix parallel growth strategies rather than emerging "outside the box" thinking. </p>
            
            <a href="#some-path">Some path</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: although this does move it to the right, it does not align it to the top as shown in `desired output` screenshot. there is a gap at the top of the `right-align` element.

Comment: @usernameabc I've edited my answer. Added top: 0; for align to the top.

Comment: yes it is working now. i was missing some of the attributes you added like `top`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like this with CSS Grid:

```css
.third-level {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<ul class="third-level">
          <li><a href="#">Resets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grids</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frameworks</a></li>
          <li >
            <div class="right-align">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
            <h5>Image placeholder</h5>
            <p>Collaboratively matrix parallel growth strategies rather than emerging "outside the box" thinking. </p>
            
            <a href="#some-path">Some path</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: when using `display: grid` there is this issue: `Safari does not yet support intrinsic and extrinsic sizing with grid properties such as grid-template-rows`. [caniuse: display: grid](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20grid). Have you overcome this with another attribute>

Comment: @usernameabc I'm pretty sure that's referring to values like min-content and max-content, not used in my example. This runs fine for me on Safari.

Comment: what safari version are you using? When i look for [min-content](https://caniuse.com/#search=min-content), under the known issue tab it says `Safari does not yet support usage with CSS Grid Layout properties such as grid-template-rows.`

Comment: @usernameabc Does not support usage of min-content with grid-template-rows. Min-content isn't in my example, and it's not necessary to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the CSS `flex` property to achieve this. And as @cale_b  mentioned on your comments,  its strongly recommended you change that pointless markup for the design you really want.

```css
.third-level {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  width:100%;
  background: #b9deb9;
  padding:0; margin:0;
}

.third-level > div {
  flex-grow:1;
  
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:2px;
  width:45%;
}

.right-align{
}
```

```html
<ul class="third-level">
          <div><a href="#">Resets</a></div>
          <div><a href="#">Frameworks</a></div>
          <div><a href="#">Grids</a></div>
          <div class="right-align">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
            <h5>Image placeholder</h5>
            <p>Collaboratively matrix parallel growth strategies rather than emerging "outside the box" thinking. </p>
            
            <a href="#some-path">Some path</a>

          </div>
        </ul>
```